# Update SUMIF formula to support filtered data

Tags: excel, subtotal

I have a table of times logged per date (and a stack of other info not relevant here)

```
logTable
Date - Project - other stuff - Hours
1 Jul - X - ... - 3 hrs
1 Jul - Y - ... - 2 hrs
2 Jul - X - ... - 4 hrs
etc.
```

I then have a formula which calculates time per day:

Note that K3 is the start of the period (i.e. Monday) to calculate the time per day for.

`=SUMIF(logTable[[#All],[Date]],"="&K3,logTable[[#All],[Hours]])`

In plain English this would be "show me the total hours from all rows with date X" - and what I need is "show me the total hours from all *currently visible, not filtered* rows with date X"

It is a basic time-logging spreadsheet. The purpose of this particular part is to display amount of time per day for a selected week, filtered by various criteria.

Unfortunately SUMIF does not seem to support filtering tables.

How can I update that formula such that it will calculate time per day but *only for unfiltered rows* in logTable? For example, I may want to filter my table by project X, and have the output update to reflect that (note that this is just an example, the table may be filtered in many other ways - the solution needs to support table filtering).

There are lots of similar questions here but I have not been able to come up with a solution based on any. Part of the confusion I think is that I'm using table and column names and most of the solutions seem to use ranges and offsets, which I don't know how to use with named tables.

Comment: I have a hacky "solution" that I am currently using but I'd like to know a better way to do this:

I have added an extra column to logTable, which simply shows whether that row is visible or not `=(AGGREGATE(3, 5, [@Hours])>0)+0)` and then in my other formulas I can use `=SUMIFS(..., ..., ...,logTable[[#All],[Visible]], 1)` however while this does work it seems to be very much a hack and I'd prefer not to have an arbitrary column in my table just to calculate whether that row is visible or not.

Comment: You are not explaining yourself clearly, so let's clarify:  you have a table.  You have applied a filter,  so only some rows are visible.  You want to get a sum of the [hours] column.  Now, here's the unclear part.  Do you want a sum of all _visible_ rows, or do you want sum of only some of the visible rows, that match some other criteria?

Comment: I want `sum of *visible, not filtered* [hours] where [date] = X` (this is then done 7 times to generate a table of times per day of the week)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here is a selection

1. change your formula to use SumIFs instead of SumIF, then you can add more criteria.

   `=SUMIFS(logTable[hours],logTable[date],G2,logTable[project],G3)`
2. Use SubTotal and filter the table. Subtotal will only calculate the visible cells

   `=SUBTOTAL(9,logTable[hours])`
3. Use the new Filter() function available with Office 365 Excel.

   `=SUM(FILTER(logTable[hours],(logTable[date]=G2)*(logTable[project]=G3)))`

In these examples, the date is in cell G2 and the project in cell G3. Adjust to suit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Unfortunately, 

1. SUMIFS doesn't support table filtering. While it could be manually written to filter specific things, I want a solution that will automatically work no matter how I filter my table.
2. Subtotal does, but then does not support filtering by date as required here.
3. This is the standalone version of Excel, not the online 365 version.

Comment: @ned subtotal _does_ work with visible only cells in tables.  If you are having trouble getting it to work,  update your Q with full details of what you have tried, what result you expected,  and what result you actually got.  Someone will be able to help you

Comment: @chrisneilsen - subtotal cannot accept IF filters. You can see quite literally the existing formula in my original post. If you can show me how to use subtotal instead of sumif in that formula, that would be great.

Clarified in plain English currently I have "show me the total hours from all rows with date X" - and what I need is "show me the total hours from all *currently visible, not filtered* rows with date X"

Comment: @NedMartin, there is no confusiuon on our end, your A is exactly what Teylyn told you, `=SUBTOTAL(9,logTable[hours])`.  To be clear, this will return the sum of _Visible Rows Only_ from table `logTable`, from column `Hours`.  If this isn't what you wnat, or you can't make it work, then please do as i asked and  "update your Q with full details of what you have tried, what result you expected, and what result you actually got."

Comment: @chrisneilsen I'm not sure what the confusion here is. SUBTOTAL would only return the subtotal of all visible rows - it does not support the ability to filter rows by a criteria - in this case, date X. Let me quote from my original question: In plain English ... what I need is "show me the total hours from all currently visible, not filtered rows *with date X*"

Comment: There is no Excel function that does what you describe, e.g. total a range by two filters, one using the visible rows, the other using a criterion in the formula. I have given you three options to arrive a t the desired result with Excel's current formulas. If you would like Microsoft to create such a function, you may want to post an idea at https://excel.uservoice.com/ If it gets sufficient votes, Microsoft will consider it.